# Fatal Error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional Value making Custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, option-type

I am trying to create a custom UITableViewCell with outlets to UILabels and UIImageViews. However, whenever i try to set any value of these outlets, the fatal error occurs. I have a UITableView inside of a regular ViewController

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
        cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            var cell: StoreTableCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell",
                forIndexPath: indexPath) as! StoreTableCell
            let currentItem = storeSection[indexPath.row]
            cell.ItemName.text = currentItem[0]
            cell.ItemDescription.text = currentItem[1]
            cell.ItemImage.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: currentItem[2])
            cell.ItemPrice.text = currentItem[3]
            return cell
    }
```

My currentItem array is never empty, and always has a string at each index.

These is my storeTableCell class:

```
class StoreTableCell: UITableViewCell{

    @IBOutlet var ItemName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var ItemImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var ItemDescription: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var ItemPrice: UILabel!

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("NSCoding not supported")
    }

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    }


}
```

The error always occurs in (cellForRowAtIndexPath) whenever I try to set one of the outlets' values, regardless of what order I assign them. Any suggestions, I'm pretty new to Swift.

Comment: Swift is complaining that you tried to use the "!" operator to force unwrap an optional that contained a nil value. It's most likely the as! failing. Are you using storyboards or nibs?

Comment: What specifically is 'the fatal error' - is there any useful message or stack trace at all? Can you debug this remotely from XCode?

Answer (score 1):

I'm betting one of your outlets is not setup correctly.  It's very easy to mess up the outlet connections to your code leaving nil references. Go to your storyboard and look at the top of your view controller for a yellow circle with a square in it.  Right click it to view all of your outlets.  You may find an old one still in there marked by a yellow warning triangle.  Remove it by clicking the x near it.